# Pushpin buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, gesture, pushpin

I'm writing a WP7 app for my university that allows users to see all of the bus routes of the campus buses, and to click on a pushpin representing each stop that will show them the different times that the buses arrive. (see http://pt.berkeley.edu/bear_transit/map.php?route_checked=p )

A sample of just one of the pushpins in my program looks like this:

```
Pushpin r1 = new Pushpin();
r1.Location = new GeoCoordinate(37.870805174152, -122.26761817932129);
r1.Content = "R1";
map1.Children.Add(r1);
```

so far I have over 
Some of these bus stops overlap with different routes and some don't. My question is, is there a simple way to handle tap gestures for **ALL** of my pushpins **WITHOUT** writing a GestureService.GetGestureListener("bus stop") for each pin?
Each stop is going to need to pull up a different set of times, as demonstrated in the above link.

Thanks for any ideas you may have :]

Comment: Do the bus stops that overlap have the exact same geocoordinate?

Comment: Use a DataTemplate, and bind the Tap event.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a collection of objects representing the data you could just loop through that and add the items there so you only need to write the add code once.
Something like:

```
foreach (var pinData in allPins)
{
    map1.Children.Add(
        new PushPin
            { 
                Content = pinData.Content,
                Location = new GeoCoordinate(pinData.Latitude, pinData.longitude)
            });
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

You may also want to add some logic about only loading the appropriate pins based on the currently displayed area on the map.

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm a novice at the WP7 language as well as VS2010.